# Working with incoming numbers in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am trying to find the network and SIM operator of the incoming call but I am not able to find that, my code finds network and SIM operator of my device only.

Here is my code:

```
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {                                   

        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        name = phoneNumber;

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

        String simOperator = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));


        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));

        }
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Also, next time please go a google research before posting a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the operator, as android isn't offering an API for that:

In theory, you could get the prefix of the number and compare it to a list of all providers, but the ability to take your number to a different provider with the old prefix is pretty much ruining that option.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was after. He wants to find out the network SIM operator for the incoming call, i.e. is the call coming from Three, T-Mobile, Vodafone etc

Comment: Actually, i am able to get incoming number but not able to fetch its operator and other related info.

Comment: will it be able to find the correct operator after portability?